# Modifying a predefined program structure

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a piece of code that is written using cakephp as follows,

```
if($this->Session->read($this->_username)){
       if(!empty($this->data)){       
          $data = array(                
                    'fullname' => $this->data['Table']['fullname'],                 
                    'lastname' => $this->data['Table']['lastname'],
                    'title' => $this->data['Table']['title'],                       
                    'language' => $this->data['Table']['language']                              
                );

                if ($this->Table->save($data)) {                            
                    $this->redirect('okpage');
                }
            }
        }
```

The built-in save function will save the data array into a database table X.
Now I would like to add another element employeeid that is to be save into a table Y, for example.
So the code above becomes

```
if($this->Session->read($this->_username)){
       if(!empty($this->data)){          
          $data = array(               
                    'fullname' => $this->data['Model']['fullname'],                    
                    'lastname' => $this->data['Model']['lastname'],
                    'title' => $this->data['Model']['title'],                      
                    'employeeid' => $this->data['Model']['employeeid'],
                    'language' => $this->data['Model']['language']                             
                );

                if ($this->Model->save($data)) {                          
                    $this->redirect('okpage');
                }
            }
        }
```

I am confused as to what should I change in the expression of if statement to save data?  because the original code to save data array is used to save data into a table X, now my insertion messes it up, which messes my mind too.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP can help you do this sort of thing automatically if you set up a relationship between the X and Y tables.

There's not enough info in your question to guess at what this relationship should be but you could have X belongs to Y, or Y has many X, or ...

Read this section in the CakePHP book: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together to get an introduction.